# Заменить адреса картинок на адреса со старого сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сайт переехал на новый домен, однако не все картинки перенеслись по новым адресам. Нужно переписать адреса утерянных картинок класса article_image на адреса со старого домена. Адреса отличаются только названием домена. 
Я пишу на jquery:

```
$('img.article_image').on('error', function() {
$(this).attr('src').replace('new-domain.ru', 'old-domain.ru'); 
});
```

Не срабатывает.
Ранее задавал вопрос с галереями - сработало. Теперь нужно для новостей

Comment: `replace` не модифицирует строку, а возвращает модифицированную строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('new-domain.ru', 'old-domain.ru'));
```